# Target and hide element in the DOM using react

Tags: reactjs

I currently using a component that I have downloaded called 'big calendar' for React. I have stylised it the way I like it to. The big calendar has a toggle button for month, day, and week. I want to hide an element when the "day" button is selected. The span class I would like to hide is 'rbc-toolbar-label'. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

current code at the moment (tried but errors):

```
    if(selectedViewType=='day'){
   //document.getElementById('rbc-toolbar-label').style.display = 'none'
  this.refs.rbc-toolbar-label.setAttribute('display', 'none')
}
```

Comment: React is not supposed to work the same way as jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.["rbc-toolbar-label"]).style.display='none'`

If you have some element you want to hide :

```
 <div ref="rbc-toolbar-label">To be hidden
 <div>
```

you need to get DOM node using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`  and then set its style using javascript